# Falling Rocks Game

Tags: c#, game, console

I have implemented the Falling rocks game in C#. The instructions are simple: Don't get hit by rocks. The game is running quite well, however there are some bugs that occur and furthermore, I would like to receive advice whether I could make the code less complicated if possible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;


// a structure to make life easier
struct Object
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public char ch;
    public ConsoleColor color;
}
class Program
{
    // in order to print characters on certain positions
    static void PrintOnPosition(int col, int row, char ch,
        ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.Gray)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.Write(ch);
    }

    // in order to print strings on certain positions
    static void PrintStringOnPosition(int col, int row, string str,
        ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.Gray)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.Write(str);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        // Some properties and variables to be used
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight = 18;
        Console.WindowWidth = 20;
        Console.BufferWidth = 20;

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        double sleeptime = 200;
        double score = 0;
        int lives = 5;

        // constructing the dwarf elements "(O)"
        Object DwarfLeft = new Object();
        DwarfLeft.x = 9;
        DwarfLeft.y = Console.WindowHeight - 1;
        DwarfLeft.ch = '(';
        DwarfLeft.color = ConsoleColor.Gray;

        Object DwarfCenter = new Object();
        DwarfCenter.x = 10;
        DwarfCenter.y = Console.WindowHeight - 1;
        DwarfCenter.ch = 'O';
        DwarfCenter.color = ConsoleColor.Gray;

        Object DwarfRight = new Object();
        DwarfRight.x = 11;
        DwarfRight.y = Console.WindowHeight - 1;
        DwarfRight.ch = ')';
        DwarfRight.color = ConsoleColor.Gray;

        List<Object> Rocks = new List<Object>();

        // Writing the instructions at the start of the game
        PrintStringOnPosition(0, 5, " The aim of the game is to avoid all the rocks. Good luck!", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
        PrintStringOnPosition(0, 9, "Pick", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
        PrintOnPosition(5, 9, (char)3, ConsoleColor.Red);
        PrintStringOnPosition(7, 9, "for lives", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
        PrintStringOnPosition(0, 10, "Pick", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
        PrintOnPosition(5, 10, '$', ConsoleColor.Green);
        PrintStringOnPosition(7, 10, "for money", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
        PrintStringOnPosition(5, 13, "Good luck!", ConsoleColor.Red);
        PrintOnPosition(17, 0, ' ', ConsoleColor.Black);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        // making the lines of play
        for (int i = 0; i <= Console.WindowWidth - 1; i++)
        {
            PrintOnPosition(i, 4, '_', ConsoleColor.White);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            // The bool values in case we get hit. They are different for the parts of the dwarf elements
            bool hit = false;
            bool hitleft = false;
            bool hitcenter = false;
            bool hitright = false;

            // the chance is for making bonuses from time to time
            int chance = randomGenerator.Next(0, 100);

            {
                Object NewRock = new Object();
                NewRock.x = randomGenerator.Next(0, 19);
                NewRock.y = 5;


                if (chance < 1)
                {
                    // It's a heart character
                    NewRock.ch = (char)3;
                    NewRock.color = ConsoleColor.Red;
                }
                else if (chance < 10)
                {
                    NewRock.ch = '$';
                    NewRock.color = ConsoleColor.Green;
                }
                else if (chance < 100)
                {
                    NewRock.ch = '@';
                    NewRock.color = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                }
                Rocks.Add(NewRock);
            }

            //moving the dwarf
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo userInput = Console.ReadKey();
                // In order to avoid the moving bug (If numerous keys are pressed, the program will execute each one)
                while (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                }
                if (userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow && DwarfLeft.x > 0)
                {
                    PrintOnPosition(DwarfLeft.x, DwarfLeft.y, ' ', DwarfLeft.color);
                    PrintOnPosition(DwarfCenter.x, DwarfCenter.y, ' ', DwarfCenter.color);
                    PrintOnPosition(DwarfRight.x, DwarfRight.y, ' ', DwarfRight.color);
                    DwarfLeft.x = DwarfLeft.x - 1;
                    DwarfCenter.x = DwarfCenter.x - 1;
                    DwarfRight.x = DwarfRight.x - 1;

                }

                if (userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow && DwarfRight.x < Console.WindowWidth - 1)
                {
                    PrintOnPosition(DwarfLeft.x, DwarfLeft.y, ' ', DwarfLeft.color);
                    PrintOnPosition(DwarfCenter.x, DwarfCenter.y, ' ', DwarfCenter.color);
                    PrintOnPosition(DwarfRight.x, DwarfRight.y, ' ', DwarfRight.color);
                    DwarfLeft.x = DwarfLeft.x + 1;
                    DwarfCenter.x = DwarfCenter.x + 1;
                    DwarfRight.x = DwarfRight.x + 1;
                }
            }
            PrintOnPosition(DwarfLeft.x, DwarfLeft.y, DwarfLeft.ch, DwarfLeft.color);
            PrintOnPosition(DwarfCenter.x, DwarfCenter.y, DwarfCenter.ch, DwarfCenter.color);
            PrintOnPosition(DwarfRight.x, DwarfRight.y, DwarfRight.ch, DwarfRight.color);

            // The new list is made in order to add the next position of the rock which is y + 1. Thus making it fall
            List<Object> newList = new List<Object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Rocks.Count; i++)
            {
                Object oldRock = Rocks[i];
                Object newObject = new Object();
                newObject.x = oldRock.x;
                newObject.y = oldRock.y + 1;
                newObject.ch = oldRock.ch;
                newObject.color = oldRock.color;

                // check if we get hit
                if ((newObject.x == DwarfLeft.x && newObject.y == DwarfLeft.y && newObject.ch == '@'))
                {
                    hit = true;
                    hitleft = true;
                }
                else if ((newObject.x == DwarfCenter.x && newObject.y == DwarfCenter.y && newObject.ch == '@'))
                {
                    hit = true;
                    hitcenter = true;
                }
                else if (newObject.x == DwarfRight.x && newObject.y == DwarfRight.y && newObject.ch == '@')
                {
                    hit = true;
                    hitright = true;
                }

                    // money
                else if (newObject.x == DwarfLeft.x && newObject.y == DwarfLeft.y && newObject.ch == '$')
                {
                    score += 500;
                }
                else if (newObject.x == DwarfCenter.x && newObject.y == DwarfCenter.y && newObject.ch == '$')
                {
                    score += 500;
                }
                else if (newObject.x == DwarfRight.x && newObject.y == DwarfRight.y && newObject.ch == '$')
                {
                    score += 500;
                }

                // lives
                else if (newObject.x == DwarfLeft.x && newObject.y == DwarfLeft.y && newObject.ch == (char)3)
                {
                    lives += 1;
                }
                else if (newObject.x == DwarfCenter.x && newObject.y == DwarfCenter.y && newObject.ch == (char)3)
                {
                    lives += 1;
                }
                else if (newObject.x == DwarfRight.x && newObject.y == DwarfRight.y && newObject.ch == (char)3)
                {
                    lives += 1;
                }

                // Add the new object in the newList until it reaches the end of the screen
                if (newObject.y < Console.WindowHeight)
                {
                    newList.Add(newObject);
                }
            }

            // consequences for being hit
            if (hit == true)
            {
                // checks if you have 1 live left. Else the game will continue until you reach -1 lives
                if (lives < 2)
                {
                    PrintStringOnPosition(0, 0, "GAME OVER!", ConsoleColor.Red);
                    // We print the X in order to see the place of casualty
                    if (hitleft == true)
                    {
                        PrintOnPosition(DwarfLeft.x, DwarfLeft.y, 'X', ConsoleColor.Red);
                    }
                    else if (hitcenter == true)
                    {
                        PrintOnPosition(DwarfCenter.x, DwarfCenter.y, 'X', ConsoleColor.Red);
                    }
                    else if (hitright == true)
                    {
                        PrintOnPosition(DwarfRight.x, DwarfRight.y, 'X', ConsoleColor.Red);
                    }
                    PrintOnPosition(17, 0, ' ', ConsoleColor.Black);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    PrintStringOnPosition(0, 0, @"           ", ConsoleColor.Red);
                    return;
                }
                // Print an X on the hit position
                if (hitleft == true)
                {
                    PrintOnPosition(DwarfLeft.x, DwarfLeft.y, 'X', ConsoleColor.Red);
                }
                else if (hitcenter == true)
                {
                    PrintOnPosition(DwarfCenter.x, DwarfCenter.y, 'X', ConsoleColor.Red);
                }
                else if (hitright == true)
                {
                    PrintOnPosition(DwarfRight.x, DwarfRight.y, 'X', ConsoleColor.Red);
                }

                // If we still have lives, the game continues
                PrintStringOnPosition(0, 0, "Press enter", ConsoleColor.Red);
                // this is made in order to avoid a bug in which when you press some letter, it prints it on the console
                // on the last position the cursor was
                PrintOnPosition(17, 0, ' ', ConsoleColor.Black);
                Console.ReadLine();
                // Clear the positions of the old objects
                PrintStringOnPosition(0, 0, @"           ", ConsoleColor.Red);
                foreach (Object rock in Rocks)
                {
                    PrintOnPosition(rock.x, rock.y, ' ', ConsoleColor.Black);
                }
                Rocks.Clear();
                newList.Clear();
                // Consequences
                lives--;
                sleeptime += 20;
            }

            // This basically makes the rocks move. The idea is - Clear the old rocks and make the new ones
            foreach (Object rock in Rocks)
            {
                PrintOnPosition(rock.x, rock.y, ' ', ConsoleColor.Black);
            }
            // The object Rocks takes the value of the new list which contains the positions of the new rocks
            Rocks = newList;

            foreach (Object rock in Rocks)
            {
                PrintOnPosition(rock.x, rock.y, rock.ch, rock.color);
            }

            // The score and lives
            PrintStringOnPosition(7, 2, "Score: " + (int)score, ConsoleColor.Cyan);
            PrintStringOnPosition(7, 3, "Lives: " + lives, ConsoleColor.Yellow);

            // Making the score increase and the speed of the game increase constantly
            score += 14.66;
            sleeptime -= 0.5;
            if (sleeptime < 100)
            {
                sleeptime = 100;
            }

            if (sleeptime > 200)
            {
                sleeptime = 200;
            }

            // Set the speed of the program
            Thread.Sleep((int)sleeptime);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the speed of the dwarf is the same as the game speed. How can I make it constant throughout the game? Furthermore, if the position of the dwarf reaches the end of the window to the right, it bounces up as well as the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things that should help.

Instead of using a keyword `Object` for your custom object using a more descriptive name like `GameObject` makes it more obvious what the object's purpose is.

Since there is a difference between the rocks and the dwarf but they have properties in common, making the main object a class and having 2 derived classes(`Dwarf`, `Rock`) makes the division between them more obvious.

Using `col`, `row` instead of `x` `y` fits better with your `PrintOnPosition` method.

Since `PrintOnPosition` and `PrintStringOnPosition` are basically the same methods with slightly different parameters having `PrintOnPosition` overloaded to take char or string makes sense here.  to make it more obvvious I changed their name to `chartoprint` and `stringtoprint`.

Since the main difference between the rocks and the dwarf is the shape.  A rock is a single character and a dwarf is a 3 character string.  By removing that property from `GameObject` and putting it in the derived classes you only need one object to represent the dwarf and since `PrintOnPosition` is overloaded the syntax stays the same.

Using all those booleans to represent a hit seems kind of awkward.  An enum,`HitPosition` with qualified names(None,HitLeft,HitCenter,HitRight) simplifies the way your hits work.  Instead of checking for `true` just check if it equals None, then use an algorithm to determine which position was hit.

An enum would also work well for the different rock shapes(Heart,Money,Rock).  This makes the code easier to understand instead of magic characters.

I went through your code and made some changes.  There are probably other areas that could be improved, but this should give you a good start.  I think I covered all of my changes, but just in case here is the modified code.  I didn't get a chance yet to look at the bug:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace FallingRocks
{
    // a structure to make life easier
    class GameObject
    {
        public int col;
        public int row;
        public ConsoleColor color;
    }
    class Dwarf : GameObject
    {
        public readonly string shape = "(0)";
    }
    class Rock : GameObject
    {
        public char shape;
    }
    enum HitPosition
    {
        None = 0,
        HitLeft = 1,
        HitCenter = 2,
        HitRight = 3
    }
    enum RockShape
    {
        Rock = '@',
        Heart = 3,
        Money = '$'
    }

    class Program
    {
        static readonly string[] hitshapes = new string[] { "", "X0)", "(X)", "(0X" };
        // in order to print characters on certain positions
        static void PrintOnPosition(int col, int row, char chartoprint,
            ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.Gray)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.Write(chartoprint);
        }

        // in order to print strings on certain positions
        static void PrintOnPosition(int col, int row, string stringtoprint,
            ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.Gray)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.Write(stringtoprint);
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            // Some properties and variables to be used
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight = 18;
            Console.WindowWidth = 20;
            Console.BufferWidth = 20;

            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            double sleeptime = 200;
            double score = 0;
            int lives = 5;

            // constructing the dwarf elements "(O)"
            Dwarf newDwarf = new Dwarf();
            newDwarf.col = 9;
            newDwarf.row = Console.WindowHeight - 1;
            newDwarf.color = ConsoleColor.Gray;

            List<Rock> Rocks = new List<Rock>();

            // Writing the instructions at the start of the game
            PrintOnPosition(0, 5, " The aim of the game is to avoid all the rocks. Good luck!", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
            PrintOnPosition(0, 9, "Pick", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
            PrintOnPosition(5, 9, (char)3, ConsoleColor.Red);
            PrintOnPosition(7, 9, "for lives", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
            PrintOnPosition(0, 10, "Pick", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
            PrintOnPosition(5, 10, '$', ConsoleColor.Green);
            PrintOnPosition(7, 10, "for money", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
            PrintOnPosition(5, 13, "Good luck!", ConsoleColor.Red);
            PrintOnPosition(17, 0, ' ', ConsoleColor.Black);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

            // making the lines of play
            for(int i = 0; i <= Console.WindowWidth - 1; i++)
            {
                PrintOnPosition(i, 4, '_', ConsoleColor.White);
            }

            while(true)
            {
                // The bool values in case we get hit. They are different for the parts of the dwarf elements
                HitPosition newHitPosition = HitPosition.None;

                // the chance is for making bonuses from time to time
                int chance = randomGenerator.Next(0, 100);

                {
                    Rock newRock = new Rock();
                    newRock.col = randomGenerator.Next(0, 19);
                    newRock.row = 5;


                    if(chance < 1)
                    {
                        // It's a heart character
                        newRock.shape = (char)RockShape.Heart;
                        newRock.color = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    }
                    else if(chance < 10)
                    {
                        newRock.shape = (char)RockShape.Money;
                        newRock.color = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    }
                    else if(chance < 100)
                    {
                        newRock.shape = (char)RockShape.Rock;
                        newRock.color = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    }
                    Rocks.Add(newRock);
                }

                //moving the dwarf
                if(Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    ConsoleKeyInfo userInput = Console.ReadKey();
                    // In order to avoid the moving bug (If numerous keys are pressed, the program will execute each one)
                    while(Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {
                        Console.ReadKey(true);
                    }
                    if(userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow && newDwarf.col > 0)
                    {
                        PrintOnPosition(newDwarf.col--, newDwarf.row, "   ", newDwarf.color);
                    }
                    if(userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow && newDwarf.col < Console.WindowWidth - 2)
                    {
                        PrintOnPosition(newDwarf.col++, newDwarf.row, "   ", newDwarf.color);
                    }
                }
                PrintOnPosition(newDwarf.col, newDwarf.row, newDwarf.shape, newDwarf.color);

                // The new list is made in order to add the next position of the rock which is y + 1. Thus making it fall
                List<Rock> newList = new List<Rock>();
                for(int i = 0; i < Rocks.Count; i++)
                {
                    Rock oldRock = Rocks[i];
                    Rock newRock = new Rock();
                    newRock.col = oldRock.col;
                    newRock.row = oldRock.row + 1;
                    newRock.shape = oldRock.shape;
                    newRock.color = oldRock.color;

                    // check if we get hit
                    if((newRock.col == newDwarf.col || newRock.col == newDwarf.col + 1 || newRock.col == newDwarf.col + 2) && newRock.row == newDwarf.row)
                    {
                        switch(newRock.shape)
                        {
                            case '@':
                                newHitPosition = (HitPosition)Enum.Parse(typeof(HitPosition), ((newRock.col - newDwarf.col) + 1).ToString());
                                break;
                            case '$':
                                score += 500;
                                break;
                            case (char)3:
                                lives += 1;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    // Add the new object in the newList until it reaches the end of the screen
                    if(newRock.row < Console.WindowHeight)
                    {
                        newList.Add(newRock);
                    }
                }

                // consequences for being hit
                if(newHitPosition != HitPosition.None)
                {
                    PrintOnPosition(newDwarf.col, newDwarf.row, hitshapes[(int)newHitPosition], ConsoleColor.Red);
                    // checks if you have 1 live left. Else the game will continue until you reach -1 lives
                    if(lives < 2)
                    {
                        PrintOnPosition(0, 0, "GAME OVER!", ConsoleColor.Red);
                        // We print the X in order to see the place of casualty                       
                        PrintOnPosition(17, 0, ' ', ConsoleColor.Black);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        PrintOnPosition(0, 0, @"           ", ConsoleColor.Red);
                        return;
                    }

                    // If we still have lives, the game continues
                    PrintOnPosition(0, 0, "Press enter", ConsoleColor.Red);
                    // this is made in order to avoid a bug in which when you press some letter, it prints it on the console
                    // on the last position the cursor was
                    PrintOnPosition(17, 0, ' ', ConsoleColor.Black);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    // Clear the positions of the old objects
                    PrintOnPosition(0, 0, @"           ", ConsoleColor.Red);
                    foreach(Rock rock in Rocks)
                    {
                        PrintOnPosition(rock.col, rock.row, ' ', ConsoleColor.Black);
                    }
                    Rocks.Clear();
                    newList.Clear();
                    // Consequences
                    lives--;
                    sleeptime += 20;
                }

                // This basically makes the rocks move. The idea is - Clear the old rocks and make the new ones
                foreach(Rock rock in Rocks)
                {
                    PrintOnPosition(rock.col, rock.row, ' ', ConsoleColor.Black);
                }
                // The object Rocks takes the value of the new list which contains the positions of the new rocks
                Rocks = newList;

                foreach(Rock rock in Rocks)
                {
                    PrintOnPosition(rock.col, rock.row, rock.shape, rock.color);
                }

                // The score and lives
                PrintOnPosition(7, 2, "Score: " + (int)score, ConsoleColor.Cyan);
                PrintOnPosition(7, 3, "Lives: " + lives, ConsoleColor.Yellow);

                // Making the score increase and the speed of the game increase constantly
                score += 14.66;
                sleeptime -= 0.5;
                if(sleeptime < 100)
                {
                    sleeptime = 100;
                }

                if(sleeptime > 200)
                {
                    sleeptime = 200;
                }

                // Set the speed of the program
                Thread.Sleep((int)sleeptime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```